# Response.getMetaData().get("location") in jersey: Why does it return a list?

Tags: location, jersey, response

In my service I am executing the following line:

```
return Response.created("someuri").build();
```

Then in my client in order to get the location I have to do

```
response.getMetaData().get("location").get(0);
```

This is all good and well, but I am wondering why on earth that is returned as a List instead of just a URI.  Can a jersey expert help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [getHeaderString](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getHeaderString(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getMetaData() returns a map of Headers in the HTTP response, and while we'd expect only one value per key most of the time, the way the HTTP protocol lists Headers line by line, there is no enforcement that header names have to be unique, so the API reflects that in its MultivaluedMap.
Moreover while we'd expect a unique value for "Location", there are valid use cases for having multiple values for other types of headers such as "Set-Cookie".